# disable tab bar item click event as fast as possible

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

[image]
[image]

When the `UITableView` cell is clicked, popup menu appears from bottom with animation and covers tab bar.
I want to prevent tab bar item's click event when cell is clicked and popup menu is appearing.
So I made a custom `UITabBarController` which comforms `UITabBarContorllerDeleagte` like below

```
// CustomTabBarController.swift
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    var enabled = true 
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return enabled
    }
}
```

instance property `enabled` is set to false when table cell is clicked and to true when popup menu disappears.
The problem is that when I click cell and tab bar sequentially very quickly, popup menu appears and also tab is changed. I think tab bar item click event is executed before variable `enabled`'s change.
Using `UITabBarController`'s `isUserInteractionEnabled` and disable each tab bar item have a same result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When the cell is clicked, you can set `tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`.
In the completion handler of the popup, after being closed, set `tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Answer (score 0):

add this on your table view delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    let tabBarController: CustomTabBarController = ... // get your tabbar
    tabBarController.enabled = false
}
```